# Disable output caching in CodeIgniter for logged in users?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter application which is mainly a news website viewed by logged out users, hence enabling output caching could really boost performance. However it is possible to login, for example as Admin, in which case caching output for pages is no longer suitable.

Is it possible to enable CodeIgniters native output caching for the 95% of regular visitors, but turn it off for those visitors who have logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if if this will work (cannot test it right now), but you may try the following: Serve the pages for the logged users with extra parameter.

```
function test(){
  if (!$this->uri->segment(3)) {
    $this->output->cache(3600);
  }
  $this->load->view('test_tpl')
}
```

The idea here is that 'controller/test' will be cached while 'controller/test/logged' shouldn't be.

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks for the suggestion, not 100% sure that will work for me but it's something to think about.